# Add cell into TableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to create a simple app where I can add class cell into a TableView, but it doesn't show up when I click Add button.I'm not sure at which part I'm doing wrong.

Here is my Main.storyboard

[image]

Here is my code in `ManageViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit

class ManageViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var classList = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //classList = ["CSC 2431","CSC 4498"]
    createAlert(title: "Add class", message: "Click plus button to add class")
    classList = ["CSC 2431","CSC 4898"]
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func onAddTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Class", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (classListTF) in
        classListTF.placeholder = "Enter Class"
    }
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (_) in
        guard let list = alert.textFields?.first?.text else { return }
        print(list)
        self.classList.append(list)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (classList.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "classCell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = classList[indexPath.row]
    return(cell)
}

}
```

Comment: Are you using correct name of reuseable identifier?

Comment: @ShauketSheikh Yes I already double checked by copy + paste the reuseable identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to set the `dataSource` on your table. You can do this on Interface Builder or in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
tableView.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 0):

Reload **tableview** on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 // Perform your async code here
  Self.tableview.reloadData()
  }
```